# Using Datepicker in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am new to Vue.js. I want to use a Datepicker in a page that uses Vue. 
Can anyone suggest what is the simplest way to use a datepicker a page that use Vue?

Comment: Have you tried searching the phrase "vuejs datepicker?"  That would seem a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have datepicker:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker

Examples (demo):
https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KhQbtTSVuU6r8VCrIdC